# How to sort list of dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am new to python and doing an assignment to implement Lai Yang Global Snapshot Algorithm. I want to order a list of messages.
I made a dictionary based on user input, but now I want to iterate for each process and sort msgs based on the time they were sent.

My dictionary structure is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{
  1: [
      {10: {'color': 'w', 'data': 4, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': 'N3FAVSNZGQP0'}}, 
      {1: {'color': 'w', 'data': 10, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': '38BRJ7PPE42V'}}
  ]
  2: [
      {30: {'color': 'w', 'data': 50, 'receiver': 1, 'msgId': 'IY09Z5TH4D2G'}}
  ]
})
```

I want it to be sorted to:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{
  1: [
      {1: {'color': 'w', 'data': 10, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': '38BRJ7PPE42V'}},
      {10: {'color': 'w', 'data': 4, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': 'N3FAVSNZGQP0'}} 
  ]
  2: [
      {30: {'color': 'w', 'data': 50, 'receiver': 1, 'msgId': 'IY09Z5TH4D2G'}}
  ]
})
```

I googled alot and browsed and tried all possible solutions. I saw sortedcontainers module but even that gave error. Below is my last attempt of lambda, which is failing too (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict')

```
for obj in sentMsgs:
    msg = sorted(sentMsgs[obj], key=lambda x:list(x.values()))
    sentMsgs[obj] = msgs
```

Other failed attempts:

```
for obj in sentMsgs:
    L = sentMsgs[obj]
    msgs = [collections.OrderedDict((k, d[k](v)) for (k, v) in l.items()) for l in L]
```

```
    msgs = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(sentMsgs[obj].items()))
    sentMsgs[obj] = msgs
```

```
    msgs = SortedDict(sentMsgs[obj])
    sentMsgs[obj] = msgs
```

Comment: You need a better abstraction.  If this is an exercise, please proceed.  But in real life you should ask yourself if an object would be a more meaningful abstraction than a dictionary.  It feels too low level to me.  Why not a dictionary of messages?

Comment: It is a dictionary of messages. The root indexes denote the processId, and within each process is the list of msgs stored. The key is the time the msg was sent and the value contains metadata of that msg.

Comment: Sort both by keys and you’re done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
messages = {
  1: [
      {10: {'color': 'w', 'data': 4, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': 'N3FAVSNZGQP0'}}, 
      {1: {'color': 'w', 'data': 10, 'receiver': 2, 'msgId': '38BRJ7PPE42V'}}
  ],
  2: [
      {30: {'color': 'w', 'data': 50, 'receiver': 1, 'msgId': 'IY09Z5TH4D2G'}}
  ]
}

for message in messages:
    messages[message].sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting each list's dicts by their key(s):

```
for a in sentMsgs.values():
    a.sort(key=list)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDda8IwEADw9/wV95YWSumX2BX6oGzzAybVjYKOPQTNXFhtQpI5SunfXlOdIgPNw10uCb87Iir9xcswFrJtFS31i9oqSKFGAH4C7yZ1q/a9BGq85gWXOAH8ix3AG6KJKSKzlXRN2Z52d4Epd2o72XTvZuHzIH@drUbzzMNN48DFu8n53h0vjIeLaT/LnqIgN57RPhwTgqtJw9uT9v7R/jU9WXoPq97bOHoMRn80ahD65BIIsBLOn@PuSfFDlWUnx47EVVxq65tWacGUthFiO2FOQAjJSo1OyRXCOgN22x4A)